# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'... I think I have tried everything

Tags: python, attributeerror

I know this issue has been addressed before, but none of the offered solutions seemed to work, perhaps it's the way my code works.

I have a very simple class:

```
class Artist:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id;
```

From another Python file, I create a new instance of the class and assign the Id value:

```
def parseartist(response):
    parsed = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
    try:
        l  = parsed.get("artists", {}).get("items", {})
        if len(l) > 0:
            f = str(l[0])
            g = f.split(",")

            id = ""
            for i in g:
                if "'id':" in i:
                    idstr = i.split(" ")
                    id = idstr[2]
                    id = id.replace("'", "")
            artist = Artist(id) 
            print(artist.id)
            return artist
    except KeyError:
        print("KeyError")
```

The Artist id value does get assigned (since I print out its value before I return it).

Then, I attempt to use this class in another Python file, and I try to get the value of the Artist Id I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

```
artistclass = jsonreader.parseartist(response)
print(artistclass.id)
```

I've iterated through `Artist` class using `dir()`, and I can see `id` as an attribute. Any idea what I'm doing wrong (besides writing bad code)?

Comment: if `len(l)` is zero, the return value is `None`.

Comment: converting `l[0]` to a string is probably wrong. What is the contents of `response`? What are your trying to do?

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. You need to fix this first for your code to work.

Comment: The indentation in the program in actually correct. It got messed up when I posted the code. Thanks.